# Saving a text file on client machine from a winforms remote desktop application

Tags: winforms, remote-desktop

I have a winforms application running over Remote Desktop, which uses SaveFileDialog to set the path where a csv file should be saved. When application is running over remote desktop, the dialog shows drives on the Server.

How can I provide functionality to save the file on the Client machine instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer - You cannot.
The reason is because you are in a remote machine and that machine cannot see your local system's hard drives. As a workaround you may consider mapping a local drive to your remote machine and that will show up in the save file dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I took the workaround of copying the data to the clipboard instead.